# Problems with Post Ajax in Asp.net core MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I can not send a Model that I am manually creating to my controller. When I send the request, it's coming up with empty properties. There is something wrong that is hindering the conversion. Does anyone know how to help me?

[image]

```
var operadoraChamadas = {
    Id: 0,
    Descricao: 'rssrrssr',
    PadraoSistema: true
};

var requestData = { operadoraChamadasViewModel: operadoraChamadas}

$.ajax({
    url: "/pessoa-gerenciar/changeFormaContato",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        alert('ok');
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Oops! Algo deu errado.");
        console.log(requestData);
    }
});


[HttpPost]
[Route("pessoa-gerenciar/changeFormaContato")]
public IActionResult changeFormaContato(OperadoraChamadaViewModel operadoraChamadaViewModel)
{
    //ViewBag.indice_new = indice;
    //return PartialView("~/Views/Pessoa/PessoaContato/_PessoaContatoAdd.cshtml", _pessoaContatoAppService.CreateNew(pessoaNatureza, formaContatoId));
    return null;
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class OperadoraChamadaViewModel
{
    [Key]
    [DisplayName("ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A Descrição é obrigatória")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [DisplayName("Descricao")]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Padrão do Sistema")]
    public bool PadraoSistema { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, you need `[FormBody]`. [This article](https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/) might help give you some background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET Core requires to add `[FromBody]` attribute to parameter to parse `application/json` content

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("pessoa-gerenciar/changeFormaContato")]
public IActionResult changeFormaContato([FromBody] OperadoraChamadaViewModel operadoraChamadaViewModel)
```

Comment: Hello @Alexander! It did not work ... Still the same problem :(

Comment: It worked!!! I changed the parameter from: "data: JSON.stringify (requestData)" to: "data: JSON.stringify (operadoraChamadaViewModel)". Thank you very much!!!!! :)