# Problems Posting in a Model with AJAX in ASP.NET CORE MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having trouble doing a Post from a Complex Model using JAX in Asp.net. The model has some properties that represent other models, but at the moment, I only need to initialize them with NULL. I do not know what is missing, but my controller is getting "null" value ... There is some problem in the conversion done on the Client side. Does anyone know how to help me?

[image]

```
var pessoaContatoViewModel = {
    Id: 0,
    PessoaId: 0,
    FormaContatoId: formaContatoId,
    FormaContatoDescricao: '',
    FormasContatos: null,
    ContatosTipos: null,
    FormaContatoTipoId: 0,
    Contato: contato,
    Observacao: observacao,
    ContatoPrincipal: contatoPrincipal,
    PessoaContatoChamadaViewModel: null,
    PessoaContatoRedeSocialViewModel: null,
    PessoaContatoEmailViewModel: null
};

$.ajax({
    url: "/pessoa-gerenciar/changeFormaContato",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(pessoaContatoViewModel),
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        alert('ok');
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Oops! Algo deu errado.");
        console.log(pessoaContatoViewModel);
    }
});


[HttpPost]
[Route("pessoa-gerenciar/changeFormaContato")]
public IActionResult ChangeFormaContato([FromBody] PessoaContatoViewModel pessoaContatoViewModel)
{
    //ViewBag.indice_new = indice;
    //return PartialView("~/Views/Pessoa/PessoaContato/_PessoaContatoAdd.cshtml", _pessoaContatoAppService.CreateNew(pessoaNatureza, formaContatoId));
    return null;
}


public class PessoaContatoViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int PessoaId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Forma de Contato")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Escolha a Forma de Contato")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public int FormaContatoId { get; set; }
    public string FormaContatoDescricao { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FormasContatos { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ContatosTipos { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Forma de Contato")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Selecione uma Forma de Contato")]
    public int FormaContatoTipoId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Contato")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo Contato é obrigatório")]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} deve ter no máximo {1} caracteres")]
    public string Contato { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Observação")]
    [MaxLength(150, ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} deve ter no máximo {1} caracteres")]
    public string Observacao { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Principal")]
    public bool ContatoPrincipal { get; set; }

    public FormaContatoTipoViewModel FormaContatoTipoViewModel { get; set; }
    public PessoaContatoChamadaViewModel PessoaContatoChamadaViewModel { get; set; }
    public PessoaContatoRedeSocialViewModel PessoaContatoRedeSocialViewModel { get; set; }
    public PessoaContatoEmailViewModel PessoaContatoEmailViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `null` passed to action because model binder got invalid values for some fields. It means that if the property is `int` you need to pass valid number, if it is `bool` you need to pass `true` or `false` and nothing else. If you need to initialize property with default value (`null`) you can just omit these properties

```
var pessoaContatoViewModel = {
    //Id: 0, omit default value
    //PessoaId: 0,
    FormaContatoId: formaContatoId, //make sure this is valid integer
    FormaContatoDescricao: '',
    //FormasContatos: null, omit default value
    //ContatosTipos: null, omit default value
    //FormaContatoTipoId: 0, omit default value
    Contato: contato,
    Observacao: observacao,
    ContatoPrincipal: contatoPrincipal, //make sure this boolean or string "true" or "false"
    //PessoaContatoChamadaViewModel: null, omit default value
    //PessoaContatoRedeSocialViewModel: null, omit default value
    //PessoaContatoEmailViewModel: null omit default value
};
```

If you pass the following model everything will work fine

```
var pessoaContatoViewModel = {
    FormaContatoId: 7,
    FormaContatoDescricao: '',
    Contato: "val",
    Observacao: "some string",
    ContatoPrincipal: true
};
```

Also condsider creating separate model for post request accepting only data you need (but this is not required)

```
public class PessoaContatoModel
{
    public int FormaContatoId { get; set; }
    public string FormaContatoDescricao { get; set; }
    public string Contato { get; set; }
    public string Observacao { get; set; }
    public bool ContatoPrincipal { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("pessoa-gerenciar/changeFormaContato")]
public IActionResult ChangeFormaContato([FromBody] PessoaContatoModel pessoaContatoViewModel)
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I think if you remove [From body] and in javascript "Json.Stringify" then it will work fine. I also remove content type.

```
var pessoaContatoViewModel = {
                Id: 1,
                PessoaId: 3,
                FormaContatoId: 0,
                FormaContatoDescricao: '',
                FormasContatos: null,
                ContatosTipos: null,
                FormaContatoTipoId: 0,
                Contato: null,
                Observacao: null,
                ContatoPrincipal: null,
                PessoaContatoChamadaViewModel: null,
                PessoaContatoRedeSocialViewModel: null,
                PessoaContatoEmailViewModel: null
            };

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/changeFormaContato",
                type: "POST",
                data: pessoaContatoViewModel,
                //contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    alert('ok');
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Oops! Algo deu errado.");
                    console.log(pessoaContatoViewModel);
                }
            });
```

Comment: The interesting thing is that your doing this with a simple model with Integer, bool, or String properties works fine. Are not properties with NULL value that are messing something up for conversion?

Comment: If you are sending null values then you should set nullable properties. like int to int?

Comment: Some properties I'm setting them to with the null value in JS. Am I doing wrong?

Comment: public int PessoaId { get; set; } this to public int? PessoaId { get; set; }. I am saying that change server side property to nullable if you send null property from the js.

Comment: I had a question previously and they helped me in the forum. Note that if I do this same action with a simple class, it is now working. In the example, I give post from the operator model operadoraChamadasViewModel. I'm trying to do the same thing only I changed the model to pesoaContatoViewModel (Model a bit more complex) and it is not working :   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55172797/problems-with-post-ajax-in-asp-net-core-mvc?noredirect=1#comment97085283_55172797

Comment: You will not need to change PessoaId. It is correct as Integer.

Comment: I have doubts if it is correct to do so:  PessoaContatoChamadaViewModel: null,
    PessoaContatoRedeSocialViewModel: null,
    PessoaContatoEmailViewModel: null

Comment: Yes. All of those which you are sending will be received null. You have to test it because it would work. Try it

Comment: I tested it, but I do not know why it is not converting. When giving post, my controller receives only null.

Comment: Are you using asp.net core? is that they told me that for asp.net core one should use the from body .. My project is in my Personal Notebook and now I'm at work. I'm going to test with your suggestion and I'll let you know if it worked he he he he