# Post controller recognizes only parameters sent by "from-data" or "x-www-form-urlencoded" from postman

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core

I have a very simple controller

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("login")]
        public IActionResult Login([FromForm]PhotoLoginDto photologin)
        {
           //doing some stuff here
        }
```

And even simpler sender on the client side:

```
  const requestOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify(photologin)
  };
  console.log("request");
  console.log(requestOptions);
  return fetch(config.apiUrl + "/PhotoLogin/login", requestOptions).then(
    handleResponse,
    handleError
  );
```

However after the sending request controller is called, IActionResult works fine but the variable photologin always has empty/default fields. "console.log(requestOptions);" displays:

```
{method: "POST", headers: {…}, body: "{"Pin":"3","LoginTime":1553604239315,"Photo":"data…ur1DU622EzHVJTtskqJGPzoooqisUBz/s0VJzWpP6E//9k="}"}
body: "{"Pin":"3","LoginTime":1553604239315,"Photo":"adsf"}"
headers: {Content-Type: "application/json"}
method: "POST"
```

If I try to use the same json via postman (body/raw) I have the same result. It works fine however as "form-data" or "x-www-form-urlencoded".
I also tried to put those three values separetly (not as one obiect) on both sides, client and server in different configurations. I replaced "FromForm" to "FromBody" or remove that attribute complitley but still nothing.
Dto props are identical as sended data. I allow all the sources for CORS.
If any of you had similar problem I would appreciate little help.

```
EDIT. Also captured response<br/>
body: ReadableStream
locked: true
__proto__: ReadableStream
bodyUsed: true
headers: Headers
__proto__: Headers
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 400
statusText: "Bad Request"
type: "cors"
```

It might siggest problem with cors, but, as I said everything is set to "allow any origin, allow any method, allow any header, allow credentials"

Comment: How are you trying to read the response in the controller? If you look in the body of the reponse there is no photologin object but the properties are placed directly on the body. I'm not sure how .net controller works but are you sure that you need to stringify the json before sending it?

Comment: I removed JSON.Stringify and there is no difference, body looks exactly the same

Comment: Use `FromBody` and see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55182424/7775908)

Comment: I used FromBody and changed all the dto fields to strings (because my client sends them as strings). Now it do not even get inside controllers constructor and I receive info about being blocked by cors despite having             app.UseCors(x => x
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());

Comment: Ok, here is working configuration: all dto fields are strings, dto received as [FromBody], post header "Content-Type": "application/json". Thanks guys a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're binding as `[FromForm]`, which literally means that it will only bind `x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data` encoded requests. If you want something like JSON or XML, then you need to use `[FromBody]`.

If your question is actually that you want to accept all of `x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data` and JSON/XML, then the answer is you cannot - not from the same action. If you need to do this, you'll need two separate actions (and routes). The common code can then be factored out into a private method. For example:

```
private IActionResult LoginCore(PhotoLoginDto photologin)
{
    //doing some stuff here
}

[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[Route("login")]
public IActionResult LoginForm([FromForm]PhotoLoginDto photologin) =>
    LoginCore(photologin);

[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[Route("login2")]
public IActionResult Login([FromBody]PhotoLoginDto photologin) =>
    LoginCore(photologin);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but unfortunately, after replacing FromForm to FromBody my argument becomes null :(