# Ajax POST object to cross domain asp.net core contoller, net::ERR_ABORTED 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core

I try to POST a user from a client app to a asp.net core controller but I got this message:

> net::ERR_ABORTED 405 (Method Not Allowed)

In asp.net core in startup.cs, I have add cors:

ConfigureServices:

```
           // Add Cors
        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader();
        }));

        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
```

Configure:

```
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod());

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
```

CredentialController:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[AllowAnonymous]
public class CredentialController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("register")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> PostUser(User user) 
    {
       Method to add user here...
    }
}
```

Here is the ajax post code:

```
const url = 'https://server-name/api/Credential/register';

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: JSON.stringify(userObject),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  crossDomain: true,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function (response) {
    console.log("response: " + response);
  },
  failure: function (response) {
    console.log("Fail: " + response.status);
  },
  error: function (response) {
    console.log("Error: " + response.status);
  }
});
```

I have checked that the URL is correct on the server side.

What is wrong?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55172797/problems-with-post-ajax-in-asp-net-core-mvc/55173042#55173042)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems with Post Ajax in Asp.net core MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55172797/problems-with-post-ajax-in-asp-net-core-mvc)

Comment: Unfortunatly not. I got the sama error message using [FromBody] in controller

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Route` you should user `ActionName`.

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("register")]
public async Task<ActionResult> PostUser(User user) 
{
   Method to add user here...
}
```

When you use `Route` your method will answer under the url: domainame/RouteName

When you use `ActionName` your method will answer under url: domainame/controller/ActionName